# Make phone call from Apple watch app

Tags: apple-watch

Can we use a button to make a phone call from the apple watch app?

For iPhone app we can use once the button is pressed:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://1111111111"]]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openURL` is silently ignored if the device is locked or the app is in the background. Additionally WatchKit doesn't contain an API for initiating a phone call.

Your best bet may be to prompt the user to open the iPhone app, possibly using Handoff, and tap a button to initiate the call from there. Not a great solution, but WatchKit is pretty limited right now.

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible from WatchOS2 :

```
if let telURL = NSURL(string: "tel:5553478") {
    let wkExtension = WKExtension.sharedExtension()
    wkExtension.openSystemURL(telURL)
}
```

[cf1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30828161/3771801),
[cf2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32379655/3771801).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this on Apple Watch itself. But there alternative ways like:

- Tell the user to call the phone in the companion iPhone app
- Use Handoff to jump from Apple Watch app to the companion iPhone app with just a tap on a button (a more user-friendly way)

NOTE: The best way is always waiting for new versions. In WWDC 2015 taking place in San Francisco (June 8-12), they will introduce WatchKit 2 with support for the companion kits on iOS and the native watch apps that run on Apple Watch without having the iPhone nearby.