# Phone call from Apple Watch with openSystem API?

Tags: ios, watchkit, phone-call, watchos-2, watchos

As I watched the WWDC 2015 session video ["Introducing WatchKit for watchOS 2"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=105) (at 13:29), I saw that it is possible to make phone calls directly on Apple Watch with the openSystem API. How can I use this API in Swift?

Comment: Did you try to find the documentation for openSystem API? Such things are usually explained in API documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`openSystemURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtension_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKExtension/openSystemURL:) method, which is available on the shared `WKExtension` object.  Pass a `tel:` URL to this method to initiate a phone call.

```
if let telURL=NSURL(string:"tel:5553478") {
    let wkExtension=WKExtension.sharedExtension()
    wkExtension.openSystemURL(telURL)
}
```

Comment: I put it in an IBAction and nothing happens when i touch the Button.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint to make sure the code is being called and that the url isn't nil?

Comment: Now it crashes after it shows the loading indicator.

Comment: My code: `@IBAction func phoneCall() {
        
        if let telURL=NSURL(string:"tel:5553478") {
            let wkExtension=WKExtension.sharedExtension()
            wkExtension.openSystemURL(telURL)
        
            
        }
    }
`

Comment: What is the crash?  I am not sure if a valid phone number is required

Comment: It's very strange...the sms is working now but the phone isn't I tried with many number's i know...maybe it's a bug in the SDK?

Comment: It's entirely possible. It _is_ a beta, after all.

Comment: it works, but prompts the user and user should accept the call process.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in beta 1 that is not allowing the use of openSystemURL on phone numbers. I've seen several sample projects as well as banged my own head against the wall attempting to get going. No implementation I've seen works. SMS works fine however.