# Phone call with Watch OS2

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, phone-call

Is it possible to start a call from the watch using Watch OS 2?
I have a button in my watch os2 app and I need a way to start a call to a precompiled number from the watch or at least to start the call in the iPhone.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible on WatchOS 2:

> Apps can initiate telephone calls or SMS messages using the openSystemURL: method of the shared WKExtension object. When you open a URL that uses the tel or sms scheme, Apple Watch redirects that URL to the appropriate system app for handling. You can also open Passbook URLs by using the openSystemURL: method to open the URL associated with a PKPass object.

Comment: I can confirm this is working in WatchOS2 with the help of WKExtension. `WKExtension.sharedExtension().openSystemURL(NSURL(string: "tel://0123456789")!)`

Comment: swift3 `WKExtension.shared().openSystemURL(URL(string: "tel://0123456789")!)`